# Inserting a date to SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am writing a small app using `WPF/C#` & `SQLITE`.

One of the functions inserts a record containing two date/time values into a `table`.

I want to know if there is a proper way to do this (to ensure that the date/month fields are stored consistently).

I have created an `INSERT` query that uses parameters alongside date variables (clsVariables.DatActivityEnd = DateTime.Now;).

```
        String cntnStr = ClsVariables.StrDb;
        var connection = new SQLiteConnection(cntnStr);
        connection.Open();
        using (SQLiteCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText =
                "INSERT INTO tblActivity ([Activity_Category], [Activity_Category_Sub], [Activity_Start], [Activity_End], [Activity_Duration]) VALUES (@ActivityCategory, @ActivityCategorySub, @ActivityStart, @ActivityEnd, @ActivityDuration);";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@ActivityCategory", ClsVariables.StrActivityCurrent));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@ActivityCategorySub", ClsVariables.StrActivitySubCurrent));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@ActivityStart", ClsVariables.DatActivityStart.ToString()));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@ActivityEnd", ClsVariables.DatActivityEnd.ToString()));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@ActivityDuration", ClsVariables.DblActivityDuration));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        connection.Close();
```

Is there anything else I should do - Thank you?

Comment: This is good, nothing more to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use sql formatted strings:

```
string sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Update:

Today I would prefer AddWithValues with Type Safety and without any Conversion:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActivityStart", ClsVariables.DatActivityStart);
```

Comment: Sorry guys - which one is it?

Comment: I use this, because in some cases I had some trouble between .net DateTime and SQL DateTime.